# Why do I get the message: 'module' object has no attribute 'load_source'

Tags: python, django

I have function:

```
def load_from_file(filepath, expected_class):

    mod_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.split(filepath)[-1])
    py_mod = imp.load_source(mod_name, filepath)
```

in templatetags file and it is ok.

But when i copy/paste this function to my view i get error:

```
'module' object has no attribute 'load_source'
```

My example view:

```
import os, imp

def get_module(request, position):
    [...]
    imod = load_from_file(settings.PROJECT_ROOT + '/core/manager/modules/' + mod.type.fileview + '.py', 'ModuleManager')
    [...]

def load_from_file(filepath, expected_class):
    [...]
```

Why this not working?

Comment: do print imp in both modules (before calling the func) and see if you get something different

Comment: Yes, i have my own module named imp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have another module named `imp`.

Either rename it, move it either to a spot later in your `sys.path` than the standard library modules or out of `sys.path` completely, or rearrange your `sys.path`.

It's most likely in the same directory as your views; if that's the case, the easiest thing to do is probably to move it to a directory where no modules import `imp` or rename it.